# how to use scrollToIndex with infiniteLoader?

Tags: react-virtualized

I use the List+InfiniteLoader combination and I'd like to specify the index at which the list should start rendering at load time. I tried setting the scrollToIndex property on the List component without success.

What would be the proper way to set the start index to render with InfiniteLoader+List ?

Answer (score 0):

setting scrollToIndex to the line number and scrollToAlignment to "start" on the list did the trick.